# How to echo out result from mysql

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, html

This is what I got:

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);
require 'db/connect.php';
if($result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM numbers")) {
    if($count = $result->num_rows) {

        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo $row['number'], ',';
        }
    }
}
?>
```

I had two column in the numbers table of mysql, they're number and date
If i want to submit my date on the webpage and echo out the number, how do I do that?(I don't want it to echo out the date)

This is what I used to sumbit:

```
   <form action="test.php" method="post">
   date <input type="date" name="date"><br>
   <input type="submit">
   </form>
```

Comment: `<input type="hidden" name="date" value="$row['date']">`?

Comment: So you want to input a date and then search your MySQL table for that date, and then echo out the number that cooresponds with the date?

Comment: @oliakaoil yes that's right! do you know any ways to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is by sending an SQL-query with `WHERE`. Although note that this requires a more careful method, in order to prevent "SQL-injections". Here's what I would do (assuming that your date-column is called `date`):

```
$prepared = $db->prepare("SELECT number FROM numbers WHERE date=?");
$prepared->bind_param("s", $_POST["date"]); //assuming that you're storing the date as a string
$prepared->execute();
$prepared->bind_result($number);
if ($query->fetch() != null) echo $number;
else echo "No numbers exists for the particular date";
```

Alternatively, you *could* modify your code like this:

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
{
    if ($row["date"] == $_POST["date"])
        echo $row['number'].',';
}
```

I would, however, advice you not to, as it's generally bad to fetch all contents when just wanting a few values (even if the second code is more simple). Also, make sure to only use the code if `!isset($_POST["date"])`, because otherwise, the `$_POST["date"]` variable will be uninitialized.

There are other methods for this, but personally I use the one above. To learn more, check out the SQL-functions in the PHP-manual, and an SQL-tutorial somewhere else.